# Trigger in MySQL s

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tr_update_logs_employees AFTER UPDATE
ON employees FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE FCount INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE MxField INT;
DECLARE FName VARCHAR(100);
SET MxField = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_Schema.columns where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'db_Learning' AND Table_Name = 'employees');
SET MxField = MxField -1;
WHILE FCount <= MxField DO
    SET FName = CONCAT("SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO FName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = db_Learning AND TABLE_NAME = employees LIMIT ", FCount, ", 1");
        IF OLD.FName <> NEW.FName THEN
        INSERT INTO upd_logs_employees(FIELD_ID, FIELD_Name, OLD_Value, NEW_Value)
        VALUES(OLD.EMPLOYEE_ID, OLD.FName, OLD.FNAME,NEW.FName);
    END IF;
    SET FCount = Fcount + 1;
END WHILE;
END$$
```

Table employees has Columns

```
(Emp_Id, Emp_Name, Salary, hire_date, Dept_id,.....)
```

Table upd_logs_employees has Columns

```
(Emp_ID, Field_Name, Old Value, New Value, TimeStamp, Current_User)
```

e.g.
When I Update as :

```
UPDATE `db_Learning`.`employees` SET `Emp_Name`='Joy', `Salary`='17500', `DOB`='1990-11-02' WHERE `Emp_id`='3';
```

I want to get all changes into  upd_logs_employees  as

```
Emp_Id = 3   Field_Name = Emp_Name    Old Value = Nancy       New Value = Joy    Timestamp = .... USER...
Emp_Id = 3   Field_Name = Salary      Old Value = 15000       New Value = 17500  Timestamp = .... USER...
Emp_Id = 3   Field_Name = DOB         Old Value = 1990-07-02  New Value ='1990-11-02' Timestamp = .... USER...
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: *```SET FName = CONCAT("SELECT COLUMN_NAME INTO FName FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = db_Learning AND TABLE_NAME = employees LIMIT ", FCount, ", 1");```* You use LIMIT without ORDER BY - this is non-deterministic and may give inconsistent total result - some columns may be skipped whereas some another may be listed more than once.

Comment: Your task needs to retrieve the column value by its name. This subtask may be solved by using prepared statement (dynamic SQL) only - but this statement type is not allowed in triggers.